# Program that runs when rows and columns are transposed

Tags: popularity-contest

I posted this to [The Daily WTF coder challenge forum](http://forums.thedailywtf.com/forums/t/10689.aspx) a few years ago but only got one response. I figure CodeGolf stack exchange might generate more interest!

**Description**

Write a program that runs when the rows and columns of the source code are transposed.

In other words, imagine each character on each line is a cell in a matrix (pad out shorter lines as necessary to make the matrix rectangular). Write a functioning program that still functions even if its "matrix" is transposed.

*This is just a creative puzzle, not a golf.*

**Details**

1. The program must execute without error and do something interesting*
2. The transpose of the program must execute without error and do something interesting, although not necessarily the same thing as the original.
3. Any language.
4. No shebang required.
5. Single row/single column entries disallowed.

*Interesting is the subjective opinion of the CodeGolf community.

**Deadline** April 15 2011

**Trivial Example**

Here's a really stupid example, but it illustrates the rules pretty well. Of course, any "symmetric" program will meet this challenge, but I encourage you to try non-symmetric programs.

```
# #####################
 print "hello,world\n";
#r
#i
#n
#t
#
#"
#h
#e
#l
#l
#o
#,
#w
#o
#r
#l
#d
#\
#n
#"
#;
```

**Transposer Reference Implementation**

Here's a perl snippet that does the type of transposing that I am talking about. *This is not the objective of the puzzle, it is just a helper tool.*

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my @matrix;
open('SOURCE', $ARGV[0]);
my $matrixwidth = -1;
my $matrixheight = 0;
foreach (<SOURCE>) {
  chomp;
  if ($matrixwidth < length $_) {$matrixwidth = length $_}
  my @row = split(//, $_);
  push @matrix, \@row;
  $matrixheight++;
}
foreach my $x (0 .. ($matrixwidth-1)) {
  foreach my $y (0 .. ($matrixheight-1)) {
    print(defined $matrix[$y]->[$x] ? $matrix[$y]->[$x] : ' ');
  }
  print "\n";
}
```

Comment: Uninteresting set of solutions: *Any* program in a  whitespace-insensitive language with single character operators and keywords (like APL, J, GoldScript, Jack Chrenshaw's TINY...) can qualify simply my writing it on one line.

Comment: I can just put `1` into a source file and have a quine that still works when transposing the lines ...

Comment: Correction: any such program that only involves single character literals.

Comment: @Joey, I don't think that would meet the first requirement (interesting behavior).

Comment: @Joey I added a rule that submissions need to be more than 1 row or 1 column in size. @dmckee I am not familiar with those languages. Can you clarify your issue? Assuming that the operators have operands, then transposing the program will modify the order of the operator and operands, potentially separating the two in a way that's not syntactically correct. Hence the challenge. Unless I'm being naive?

Comment: mehaase: That's unfortunately a purely subjective criterion and very hard to judge. So generally you don't like quines, apparently :-). Still, what dmckee said holds true, I can just take nearly any Golfscript program fitting into a single line and call that a transposable program.

Comment: @mehaase: Your edit disallowing single column/line solutions solves the problem. They are just languages where everything is one character long and newlines are not significant.

Comment: Anyone up for doing this in a [Befunge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Befunge)-type language?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### c

Not-quite-trivial, not-quite-symmetric solution that prints it's command line arguments, one per line. As shown it prints them in order, as transposed in reverse order.

```
/*******ipcc;m(acaw-{aa) 
********nuohiairhrh-prr; 
********ttnaningagiaugg} 
******** ssrtntcrvlrtvc} 
******** (t*   ,*)egs[]  
********   s    *{(c(    
********   )       )     
*******/                 
int                      
puts(                    
const                    
char*s)                  
;int                     
main                     
(int                     
argc,                    
char**                   
argv){                   
int i;                   
for(i=1;                 
i<argc;                  
i++)                     
{puts(                   
argv[i]                  
);}}
```

Comment: Haha! Very interesting approach! +1

Comment: I like the starry blob in the upper-left corner ;)

Comment: @mehaase: Frankly I didn't think it was philosophically different than your "trivial" example. I just thought the trick with the block comment was cute. In principle it is extensible to any two complete programs.

Comment: Well, april 15 came and went with no other submissions :( But congrats, you win the mini-contest!

Answer (score 16):

Here's one I came up with when I originally wrote the challenge a few years back. It's a perl script that can transpose other scripts. You can run it on itself, save the output as a new script, then run that new script on itself to get the original.

```
#######       p           $f f   ]'
#      ofm    u        $  ho o   -
#      poy    s        w  +r r  p>'
#      er ####h########=##+ #   r[}
    open   'M' , $ARGV[ 0]  ; # i$p
  for(;   <M>  ; ){         #   nxr
      #((@             $  }( (  t]i
      #';r             #   $ $   ?n
      #M<=    @        r   x y   $t
      #'M     m        +   = =   m
      # >     ,        1   0 0   ["
my @r=   $_ =~ /./g;#  >   ; ;   $\
      #  _ /  \                # yn
push @m,     \@r;              # ]"
      # ;=    r            $ $   -}
      #  ~    ;        $   x y   >
$w=($#r   + 1>        $w)      # [
?$#r+1:     $w ;$h++}# ?   < <   $
for (     $x=0 ;$x<$w;         # x
          $x++ ){              # ]
for (     $y=0 ;$y<$h;
          $y++ ){           #$
  print               #$   $ h  d:
defined                #   w ;  e
      #$)/    #        r   ; $  f
      #A{.             +   $ y  i
      #R#/             1   x +  n
      #G g             :   + +  e
      #V ;                 + )  d
     $m[  $y]->[$x]
      #0 #                 ) {  $
 ?$m[$y]->[$x]:' '}          #  m
      #)               $   {    [
      #;               w        $
  print "\n"} #        ;        y
```

Comment: Look! Line noise in a sparse matrix!